# Loop through ee.ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine to sum pixels of each individual part, and return value(s)

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have an image collection :

```
var imcol = ee.ImageCollection(table.map(colFunc));
```

that contains values for total number of x species supported in each pixel for each image. I want to loop through the collection somehow and use a function like this:

```
var sum_calc = function(feature){
  return feature.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: fc,
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
};
```

to sum the values of each image to show (essentially) carrying capacity of each image.
I am very new to javascript and Earth Engine. what would be the best way to go about this? I just need the sum value from each image in any format.

Comment: `ImageCollection` holds `Images` and `FeatureCollection` holds `Features`, which are basically geometries with properties (points, polygons, etc). As I understand, you have a raster Image holding *values for total number of x species supported in each pixel*, but you have many Images? what, for different time? different location? In which region you want to `sum` values of all pixels?

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is correct, my imagecollection contains collections of rasters in different locations that have the number of species x that is supported in each pixel. The collection does not contain different timestamps. I would like to sum the values of all pixels for ALL of the images in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function and see if it is what you want.

```
var col = ee.ImageCollection("XXXXXX") // YOUR COLLECTION
var sum_band = function(collection, bandname, scale) {

  var ini = ee.Dictionary().set(bandname, 0) // initial value
  var f = function(img, dict) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(dict)  // cast dict
    var before = ee.Number(d.get(bandname)) // get value from last img
    var band = img.select(bandname) // select only the wanted band

    // Sum all pixels
    var val = band.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
      geometry: img.geometry(),
      scale: scale,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    }).get(bandname) // as it returns a dict, get the actual number

    var sum = before.add(ee.Number(val)) // sum before with actual

    return d.set(bandname, sum) // rewrite the value
  }
  var sum = ee.Dictionary(col.iterate(f, ini)).get(bandname)  // apply the function and get the value
  return ee.Number(sum) // return the sum as a number (change to return sum if you want the dict)
}

var number_of_species = sum_band(col, BANDNAME, 30) // replace BANDNAME
```

Don't forget to replace XXXXXX with collection's ID and BANDNAME with the name of the band that holds the values you want to sum.

Comment: thank you for the response. The function you wrote seems to be working, but I am having trouble with my computation timing out. The image collection covers a large region (several US states) at 30 meters. Here is the code now : [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/39bf765ea5fba52b6c680e010f2c3852)  If you have any suggestions to deal with this here great, otherwise I will maybe post anew topic.

Comment: Hi Stephen,  If your computation times out, either reduce the region, or try to export it to Drive, or to an asset.  The earth engine gives you a lot more time (days) to do a calculation if you export.